# Should a Java persistence entity have a common parent as the regular object?

Tags: java, persistence

I'm cleaning up some code, and I have a class with an entity that implement a lot of the same behaviour.  Should I combine that behaviour into a parent that both inherit or is there a reason to keep them separate?

(There are also some transfers of data between the entity and normal class that would be made easier if I could upcast to a method that would pass data between them)

Also what to do about the database specific additions to the shared variable?

For example, in the below code, should I create a class `MyBase` and extract `prop1` plus its getters and setters to the `MyBase` class and then have `MyObject` and `MyObjectEntity` both extend `MyBase`?

Normal:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String prop1;

    public MyObject() {}

    public String getProp1() {
       return prop1;
    }

    public void setProp1(String prop1) {
       this.prop1 = prop1;
    }

    public void doSomethingNormal() {
       //Do something normal
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyObjectEntity
{
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String prop1;

    public MyObjectEntity() {}

    public String getProp1() {
       return prop1;
    }

    public void setProp1(String prop1) {
       this.prop1 = prop1;
    }
    public void doSomethingEntity() {
       //Do something entity like
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally depends. Maybe an interface is more appropriate, and a property-copy util like Commons' BeanUtils. Hard to say with the info given. Using a normal class as an entity base class can cause a different set of problems depending on persistence framework, how/if reflection is used, etc.

Comment: Is your question, should you have a `MyBase` class with `getProp1` ad `setProp1` methods, and then have `MyObject` and `MyObjectEntity` both extend `MyBase`?

Comment: Other options: you could combine the classes into a single Entity.  (You can still instantiate and use an Entity as a POJO without persistence.)  
And instead of using subclasses, you could extract the common properties into a delegate class (has-a instead of is-a) and annotate that delegate with `@Embeddable`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Using Hibernate as the persistence framework, from what I googled didn't seem to cause any problems

Comment: @wrschneider99 yes that is correct

Comment: @wrschneider99 I can't combine the two objects as I'm working with refactoring a large project and changing all references to the original class to the entity would be beyond the scope of the current refactoring, also they are both already large classes that should have some functionality factored out in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being unable to do this as it caused problems with my old serialized objects, and settled for re factoring as much as I could within the class.